# Reportlab - Add two Paragraphs into one table cell

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I have a table which is build up like the following:

```
styleN = styles["Normal"]

data = []
table_row = ['ID', 'Some Information']
data.append(table_row)

table_row = []
table_row.append(Paragraph(object.ID, styleN))
table_row.append(Paragraph(object.some_information1, styleN))

data.append(table_row)
t = Table(data, (6*cm,6*cm,2*cm,2*cm,2*cm), row_heights, style=ts)
```

Now I want to achieve that I can add into the second cell a second paragraph containing object.some_information2.

Some more or less pseudo - code to illustrate what I want to achieve:

```
table_row = []
table_row.append(Paragraph(object.ID, styleN))
info1 = Paragraph(object.some_information1, styleN)
info2 = Paragraph(object.some_information2, styleN)
info_paragraphs = info1 + info2 
table_row.append(info_paragraphs)

data.append(table_row)
t = Table(data, (6*cm,6*cm,2*cm,2*cm,2*cm), row_heights, style=ts)
```

Comment: i guess we need some more information, because i don't see why just doing `table_row.append(info1); table_row.append(info2)` wouldn't work?

Comment: When you do like you proposed you add another column, which is not what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got feedback in the reportlab google group and it is actually very easy to achieve. Only add a list of paragraphs into the cell.

```
styleN = styles["Normal"]
data = []
table_row = ['ID', 'Some Information']
data.append(table_row)
table_row = []
table_row.append(Paragraph(object.ID, styleN))
paragraphs = []
info1 = Paragraph(object.some_information1, styleN)
info2 = Paragraph(object.some_information2, styleN)
paragraphs.append(info1)
paragraphs.append(info2)
table_row.append(paragraphs)
data.append(table_row)
t = Table(data, (6*cm,6*cm,2*cm,2*cm,2*cm), None, style=ts)
```