# Reportlab: Different styles in table cell

Tags: python, pdf

I make a application in django/reportlab and it full of tables. I found that in reportlab tables - one cell - one style. I want smth like that in my cell
[scr1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM4Iu.jpg). It looks like `______ J.D. Smith <br/>   (sign here)`
Reportlab has `<super>` function, but it only rise letters, MS Word makes them smaller. And I can't find any `tags` for `TAB`, like `<br/>`

And the question - is there any possibility to make how I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why I couldn't find it yesterday, but the answer is - list of paragraphs. 
Full answer you can find here

[Reportlab - Add two Paragraphs into one table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810008/reportlab-add-two-paragraphs-into-one-table-cell)